# Write ADC data to memory and back to DAC (without MCU)

Tags: adc, dac, ram, sram

Is there a way that is not too complex way to implement ADC -> SRAM -> DAC data transmission without the usage of the microcontroller?

The application is to implement the audio loop of some sort, to put the audio input chunk to the memory, with an ability to stop the "ADC -> SRAM" process, to keep previously acquired data in the memory.

It does not have to be a high fidelity (I have 8-bit ADC/DAC in mind).

*UPD:*
I want to do this for the educational purposes, so I'm not looking for the all-rational/optimal solution.

Comment: It depends what you might regard as complex. I built one back in the 80s that could slow down and speed up what was stored in memory and it didn't use a micro.

Comment: Sounds like a DMA controller

Comment: @Andyaka I mean not to use too much circuitry to make it work, but I'm curious what it the way to do this anyway.

Comment: Choose an ADC, choose a DAC, choose some memory and provide data sheet links.

Comment: @Andyaka do you mean that there is no generic way to implement it? I'm not asking for the complete solution :)

Comment: No, there is no generic way because ADCs come in all shapes and sizes regards their digital interfacing requirements. Ditto DACs and ditto memory. So choose devices.

Comment: I did this in the late 70s with Burr Brown ADC > DAC for each sample at high sample rates. I found the DAC was very linear and Monotonic but the ADC was not with Vref noise inside the Hybrid IC so there were dead bands at some binary intervals like x1111 to x1000 but only on Mil-STD-883 hybrids. (BB Process flaw). Just route the appropriate signals for Data ready to Data output to DAC

Comment: You'll be building a small state machine (possibly just one FF) which alternately selects a read address (via a 2:1 MUX) and a write address to SRAM, and generates the read and write strobes. Every second cycle it increments a READ address counter, and (unless you have pressed the STOP button) also a WRITE address counter. About a dozen TTL chips in all, depending on the length of the counters. Use ADC and DAC with parallel I/O.  (yes an MCU is much simpler)

Comment: The problem with the "a microprocessor complicates things" is that you can go out and buy a microcontroller that does all of this already, all by itself -- just add code, slap it on a board, and go.  The alternative is to use the dozen chips that @BrianDrummond mentioned, and then find out that all the discrete ADCs and DACs available today are horribly fast for your needs, or have microcontroller-specific interfaces, or are horribly old and teetering on the edge of obsolecence.

Comment: @TimWescott well, I want to do this more in educational purposes, to use the digital ICs but to avoid the MCU and a software part.

Comment: Could you edit your question to highlight that you want to do this for educational reasons?  Practically, it's cheaper and faster to buy a microcontroller with 100,000 gates in it than it is to build this up with the dozen or so chips you'd need.  But doing it for educational reasons is solid.

Comment: @Andyaka I found TLC0820AC ADC (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc0820a.pdf) and TLC7524 DAC (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc7524.pdf) from TI, with parallel interface, which are currently available. Not sure about the memory chip though.

Comment: You can do it all with a cheap CPLD. If you don't know HDL design though, there's a learning curve there similar to that with microcontrollers. The timing will be easier to make predictable than a microcontroller but that may not have been an obstacle anyway. If you want it simple, the CPLD logic design can derive control signals and addresses all off of one long counter. As ever, though, it depends what you're trying to do and what your priorities are.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do something like this. I saw a design from the 80's that used a ROM (27C64) and a 74HC4040 counter to generate a sine wave. The CD4017 counter also had one of it's upper address lines routed to an ADC that caused the ADC to sample and spit out a serial stream.

You could conceivably get an old ADC with a parallel output and use a counter to poll it and activate the WR lines of a parallel RAM, and then use a few flip flops to read the value back (I assume it's a delay you might be after)

But instead of building a physical system with 74HC series logic, the better way is to use an FPGA between the ADC and the DAC, especially if you don't need that much RAM, it would be much easier and more configurable.